# How can I change the default temp directory used by Release Management Server 2013 Release 4

Tags: alm, ms-release-management

Release Management Server defaults to the system drive in the current users local temp directory. I was scanning through its various configuration files but I could not seem to figure out if you can repoint its working directory to another drive. The builds are eating up space on my C drive. It there any way to repoint it to another drive?

Comment: Agent-based or vNext releases? Are you talking about space used on the target server or on the RM server? If Agent-based, how do you transfer your files, directly UNC Path or through HTTP via the RM Server?

Answer (score 0):

Release Management Server is mostly a database that can be put wherever you like using standard SQL Server techniques for moving databases. Pretty sure it doesn't have a working directory - or are you doing something exotic?

The RM Deployment Agent receives builds on target nodes at C:\Users\$AccountNameUsedToRunDeployerService$\AppData\Local\Temp\RM\T\RM. I haven't seen anywhere to change this but you you can configure cleanup settings from the RM Client - Administration > Settings > Deployer Settings and maybe choosing something more aggressive may help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is actually really easy: Change the %TEMP% environment variable for the deployer user.

That said, the defaults for temp file retention are a bit crazy: 7 days!